# Launching a GUI Windows app at a time read from a file

Tags: c#, windows, service, scheduler

Here is my requirement:  an application (with an inbuilt browser) that pops up to remind the user to complete a certain task online. If the user has completed it, he can dismiss that pop-up, or he can postpone it for a predetermined time.

Speaking architecture-wise, the app reads the next-remind-time from a normal text file, and has to launch this application at (an approximation of about 1 hour will do) this time. Problem I am facing is, Windows service cannot call GUI applications, this will be an installable EXE, I cannot ask everybody to schedule it from Task Scheduler.

How do I go about launching that application at around that time in the file?

Comment: Have the application already launched, but sitting in the systray without a visible UI until the right time comes around - then you pop up the form.

Comment: Agree with @J.Steen: Write a WinForms program that normally is only seen as an icon in the system tray. Do a Google search for "c# winforms notifyicon". Force the users to always run it by including it in their Startup folder, or by starting it via the registry.

Comment: The application launched, as in a startup? Or is a service communicating with the hidden app using an IPC pipe better?

Comment: What I'm suggesting (and what I think @J.Steen is also suggesting) is that you don't need a Windows service program. Just a Windows GUI program (WinForms or WPF) that runs mostly in the background, and only pops up when you want to show a popup. Like Messenger or Skype or programs like that.